# Can a folder have 2 or more owners?

Tags: permissions, folder

Can I set 2 or more owners for one folder?

For example:

- 2 users can read/write,
- DC group users can read,
- others can't see

How to I achieve the above configuration on that folder?

Comment: about owner > owner will be one cant be 2

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do this by using groups or ACL (access control lists).

You can add multiple users to a single group, and then apply that group as having access.

Or, you can enable ACL on your ext4 filesystem by adding acl to the list of mount options for your partition.

Then, install [eicel](http://packages.ubuntu.com/eicel) to configure the access.

Comment: ACL is the way to go.

Comment: Acl should be enabled by default in ext4.

Answer (score 1):

```
                                 Permissions
```

Every file/folder on the system has associated with it a set of permissions. Permissions

tell LINUX what can be done with that file/folder and by whom. There are three things you

can (or can't) do with a given file:

read it,

write (modify) it

execute it

```
mkdir /practice

ls –ls /practice

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 512 Nov 2  17:38 /practice
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

### ( READ IT )