# Restore root user ownership

Tags: server, 16.04, permissions, root, vps

Long story short, I have been working with a Digital Ocean droplet to learn a bit more about managing my own server. Somewhere along the line, I managed to set the ownership of some directories to another user (serverpilot), and my root user can no longer see or access them.

I have two users on the server, one (root) with sudo privileges and the other is a basic user (serverpilot).

When I ssh into the server with root, I am unable to see a bunch of directories. When I do so via the serverpilot use, I can see them all. Doing `ls -l` shows the owner as 'serverpilot'.

Since 'serverpilot' doesn't have sudo privileges, how can I reset the owner back to 'root', so both 'root' and 'serverpilot' can access the directories? Do I have to boot the server in recovery?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 if that makes a difference.

**Edit:**
As per the comments of @davidfoster below, the output of `getfacl . wp-content` is as follows:

```
# file: .
# owner: serverpilot
# group: serverpilot
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:serverpilot:rwx       #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:r-x
default:group::r-x
default:group:serverpilot:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: wp-content
# owner: serverpilot
# group: serverpilot
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:serverpilot:rwx       #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:r-x
default:group::r-x
default:group:serverpilot:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

And the parent directory (public):

```
# file: .
# owner: serverpilot
# group: serverpilot
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:serverpilot:rwx       #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:r-x
default:group::r-x
default:group:serverpilot:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: public
# owner: serverpilot
# group: serverpilot
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:serverpilot:rwx       #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:r-x
default:group::r-x
default:group:serverpilot:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99767/can-a-folder-have-2-or-more-owners) could help. Let me know if you're issue is something other than what I linked.

Comment: Try with:  $> chmod -R 777 directory

Comment: What are the access permissions on those directories? You can see them with `ls -ld <PATH>`. A user (including `root`) doesn't need to own a file or directory to see its content with the right permissions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Under the 'root' account it says that the file/directory doesn't exist (I'm unable to see the directory the command line via `ls`). Under the 'user' user, the directories are listed and the output is `drwxr-xr-x+ 10 user user 4096 Nov 8 19:06 wp-content`.

Comment: So you're using access control lists in addition to POSIX access control. What's the output of `getfacl . wp-content` (i. e. `wp-content` and its parent directory)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I went ahead updated the initial question and added the output. To be clear, the original account 'user' should have been 'serverpilot', so I have updated that above as well.

Comment: I have no idea why `root` would have no read access on any of those directories. Can you verify that all parent directories are readable and traversable by "other"? Maybe `sudo` is configured to use a different user. What's the output of `sudo id`?

Comment: How did the story end? What was the solution?